Light switch (in a series of three) shuts off power to the entire bedroom
My problem is there is a light switch in the master bedroom that cuts power to the entire room (fans, outlets, lights, closets, etc) when turned off. I need to figure out how to fix that.
Details:
There are three two-way light switches. The first switch (on the left) cuts power to the entire room (fans, outlets, lights, etc) when turned off. It has a black power wire connected on the top right. It has another black cable connected on the bottom right that is then daisy chained to the bottom right of the other two light switches. The middle light switch turns off fan lights and has a red wire connected to the top right. The right switch turns off the fan itself (but not the fan lights) and has another black wire connected to it.
Edit: I want the first light switch to not turn off power to the entire room, after that I am flexible. It can shut off an outlet, it can go away entirely... whatever seems best.

Pictures:
https://i.imgur.com/TiP6yPr.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/zGuliMU.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/ouwEE3C.jpeg
https://i.imgur.com/TW1xwyA.jpeg

you seem to have forgotten to ask a question. what do you want the left switch to do instead,  (nothing?  only switch the outlets?)

I have updated the original question with pictures and a desired end-goal/question.

Based on what you've stated, after turning off the breaker that controls the circuit, remove the two black wires from the first switch on the left and connect them together with the proper connector. That's it. You can then remove the switch on the left and replace the cover plate with a three gang with two switches.

First step, find out which wire is the permanent live coming from the panel. Based on your description, I suspect this is the wire connected to the top of switch 1.
Once you have that wire, connect it to the pigtails that go to the second and third switch and a new pigtail to the first switch. This way, the switches will operate independent of each other.
